# How can I use date and time selectors in OneNote 2013?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

The default note template in OneNote 2013 has date and time selectors underneath the note title, which automatically inputs the date and time when the note is created and can be manually adjusted by clicking on the calendar/ clock icons.

How can I use these date and time selectors elsewhere in my notes? And can I attach them to note containers?

I am aware that date and time can be inserted from the Insert ribbon, but these are not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't I'm afraid, it isn't available as data. OneNote isn't an information management tool as such, just a notebook.